# Are Tx process parallel? How are the account data guaranteed not overrided each other by simultaneous Tx?

Tags: account, account-data, runtime

As stated in title.

Does  runtime sort all input account an add mutex-locker to those accounts that are mutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anatoly explains the Sealevel runtime in this blog article: https://medium.com/solana-labs/sealevel-parallel-processing-thousands-of-smart-contracts-d814b378192

TL;DR: All transactions must specify in advance which accounts are writable. All transactions that do not write in the same piece of state can be processed in parallel.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful information.